# There is a natural isomorphism of chain complexes $K_{.}(x) \simeq K_{.}(x_1) \otimes_R ... \otimes_R K_{.}(x_n).$ where $K_{.}(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I try to solve exercise 1.3.1, (d)(page 4) from here http://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/minicourses/algebra/sather-wagstaff.pdf

For $x = x_1,... ,x_n$, there is a natural isomorphism of chain complexes
$$K_{.}(x) \simeq K_{.}(x_1) \otimes_R ... \otimes_R K_{.}(x_n),$$ where $K_{.}(x)$ is the Koszul complex associated to $x$.

I supposed that it can be proved by induction on $n$, using (b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll prove it by induction on $n$.

For $n=1$ it's true.

$n\geq 2$.

Let $x=x_1,...,x_{n+1}$.

We suppose that $ K_{.}(x_1) \otimes_R ... \otimes_R K_{.}(x_n) \simeq K_{.}(x_1,...,x_n)$.

We want to show that $K_{.}(x_1,...,x_n)\otimes_R K_{.}(x_{n+1})\simeq K_{.}(x_1,...,x_{n+1})$.

$(K_{.}(x_1,...,x_n)\otimes_R K_{.}(x_{n+1}))_i\simeq  (K_{.}(x_1,...,x_n))_i\bigoplus (K_{.}(x_1,...,x_n))_{i-1}=\bigwedge ^ i R^n \bigoplus \bigwedge^{i-1}R^n$

has rank $C_n^i +C_n^{i-1}=C_{n+1}^i$.

On the other hand $(K_{.}(x_1,...,x_{n+1}))_i=\bigwedge^{i} R^{n+1}$ has rank $C_{n+1}^i$.

They have the same rank, so they are isomorphic.

Comment: This is not a full proof. You just checked that for two chain complexes $C_\bullet$ and $D_\bullet$, you have $\operatorname{rk} C_i = \operatorname{rk} D_i$ for each $i$. What is missing is a family of isomorphisms $f_i\colon C_i \xrightarrow{\cong} D_i$ commuting with the differentials on $C_\bullet$ and $D_\bullet$.

Answer (score 3):

By the definition you are supposed to use in this exercise, the Koszul complex
$$K (x) = K (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$
is the following thing. One considers a free $R$-module $F$ of rank $n$ and its exterior powers:
$$0 \to \Lambda^n (F) \to \Lambda^{n-1} (F) \to \cdots \to \Lambda^2 (F) \to F \to R \to 0$$
Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be a basis of $F$. Then the differentials
$$d_k\colon \Lambda^k (F) \to \Lambda^{k-1} (F)$$
are given by
$$e_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k} \mapsto \sum_{1 \le j\le k} (-1)^{j+1} \, x_{i_j} \, e_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{e_{i_j}} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k}$$
(here $\widehat{e_{i_j}}$ means that this term is being omitted from the exterior product).

Now the key observation is that we have natural isomorphisms
$$\tag{*} \bigoplus_{p+q = k} \Lambda^p (F_1) \otimes_R \Lambda^q (F_2) \xrightarrow{\cong} \Lambda^k (F_1\oplus F_2)$$
given by
$$a_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge a_p \otimes b_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge b_q \mapsto a_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge a_p \wedge b_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge b_q.$$
This gives an isomorphism of complexes
$$\tag{**} K (x_1,\ldots,x_{n_1}) \otimes_R K (y_1,\ldots,y_{n_2}) \cong K (x_1,\ldots,x_{n_1},y_1,\ldots,y_{n_2}).$$
Namely, (*) is an isomorphism of objects in each degree $k$, and I'll leave it to you to check that it commutes with the differentials.

Then by induction, (**) implies that
$$K (x_1) \otimes_R \cdots \otimes_R K (x_n) \cong K (x_1,\ldots,x_n).$$

---

In the exercise you refer to, one is supposed to check that
$$K (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \cong K (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) \otimes_R K (x_n),$$
so feel free to rewrite (**) for $n_1 = n-1$ and $n_2 = 1$. However, the general isomorphism (*) is very important; in particular, it implies Vandermonde's identity
$$\sum_{p+q=k} {m\choose p}\,{n\choose q} = {m+n \choose k}.$$